# Issues related to Migration of windows server 2003 to windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, asp-classic

We are trying to migrate windows server 2003 to windows server 2008 for our application.
During migration process, we are facing some of the issues related to configuration and windows based configuration as architecture is totally different in 2003 and 2008 server.
our application is using vb6 and classic ASP.

Issues we are facing:-

1)  When we are trying to register a dll, it’s not getting register.
Active X can't create object 
I checked dependency walker it's showing ieframe.dll and GPSVC.dll  not found.
2)  Our application is not able to read Global.asa  i.e. present in root directory of our site created in IIS7.5.
3)  Our application is trying to reach ORACLE 32 bit driver in 32 bit ODBC data source. But by default in 64 bit OS, it is making connection with 64 bit ODBC data source.